# GreenDao Foreign Key Concept and one-to-many relationship

Tags: android, orm, foreign-key-relationship, greendao, table-relationships

For one to Many relationship how can i define foreign key constraint.
I did all the available solution but still facing the issue of no foreign key. Does Green-Dao support foreign key constraint ? if it is not support yer than how to use relationship, is it worth to create such ORM based relation ship with Green-Dao.
Its not saving other entity object inside the parent entity like Hibernet.
Please share some dummy code snippet to achieve this feature.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

GreenDAO does not create foreign key nor cascade rules when you define relations. The relation exist just in the greenDaoModel

[GreenDao Relations](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/)

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id private Long id;
    private long customerId;

    @ToOne(joinProperty = "customerId")
    private Customer customer;
}

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id private Long id;
}
```